# Real Analysis Integration Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Say $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous, $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, and there is a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) > 0$. Prove $\int_a^b fdx > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Since $f$ is continuous, what can you say about a small region around $c$?